# Conflito ao abrir várias telas no menuStrip - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tenho 3 formulários.

- Formulário Pai (Principal)
- Formulário Filho (Serviços)
- Formulário Filho (Fornecedores)

O que está acontecendo.. eu bloqueie a pessoa de tentar abrir mais de 1 vez o mesmo formulário, porém quando ela tenta abrir outro formulário (**e tenha outro já aberto**) da erro:

Código que verifica se o formulário já está ativo - **Evento click do menuStrip**:

```
private void serviçosToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Verifica se já existe o mesmo formulário aberto para não sobrecarregar de processos iguais

            bool aberto = false;

            foreach (frmCadastroServico f in this.MdiChildren)
                if (f.Name == "frmCadastroServico")
                {
                    f.Activate();
                    aberto = true;
                    break;
                }

                if(!aberto)
                {

                    frmCadastroServico CadastroServico = new frmCadastroServico();
                    CadastroServico.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                    CadastroServico.MdiParent = this;
                    CadastroServico.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    CadastroServico.Show();
                }

        }
```

[image: MenuStrip]

Código do erro:

```
System.InvalidCastException ocorrido
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'Projeto.frmCadastroFornecedores' no tipo 'Projeto.frmCadastroServico'.
  Source=Projeto
  StackTrace:
   em Projeto.frmPrincipal.serviçosToolStripMenuItem1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\Projeto\Projeto\frmPrincipal.cs:linha 43
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   em Projeto.Program.Main() em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\Projeto\Projeto\Program.cs:linha 19
```

Acredito que quando eu selecionar uma opção no menuStrip tudo que estiver aberto deverá fechar antes (não tenho certeza), alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu `foreach` está tentando dar um cast em todos os formulários abertos, isso vai dar `Exception` porque há outros tipos de formulários abertos que não são do tipo `frmCadastroServico`.

Use o `OfType<T>` no seu `foreach`.

**Exemplo:**

```
foreach (frmCadastroServico f in this.MdiChildren.OfType<frmCadastroServico>())
```

**Ou:**

Troque a declaração da variável por `var` e dentro do `foreach` tente dar um `cast` para o tipo especificado.

```
foreach (var f in this.MdiChildren)
{
   var frmServico = f as frmCadastroServico;

   if(frmServico != null)
   {
      // Se entrou quer dizer que este form é do tipo frmCadastroServico
   }

   // Se necessário faça o mesmo para outros forms...
}
```

Comment: Ficou show, resolvi com esse OfType<T> - alias o que ele fez?

Comment: Ele é um filtro de tipo (type), ele retorna apenas os itens que são do tipo que você especificou.